# Substitute for org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.HTML in jsf 2.3

Tags: jsf, myfaces

In our application we used the constants from following myfaces Interface: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/myfaces/site/publish/myfaces-commons/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/myfaces/renderkit/html/package-summary.html

Getting rid of myfaces, is there a substitute in jsf 2.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no alternative for it - but you can just use plain string or create your own constants.
Mojarra may have similar constants but just dont use MyFaces or Mojarra internal classes.